# Token Parsing Error .. encountered \' .. in Beanshell?

Tags: java, beanshell

I am trying to run the following Beanshell code--

```
assignee.toString()!=''
```

Here 'assignee' is a variable in Beanshell context.

But I am getting the following error--

```
Caused by: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``assignee.toString()!='';'' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 1, column 23.  Encountered: "\'" (39), after : "\'": <at unknown location>

at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Unknown Source)
at org.webharvest.runtime.scripting.BeanShellScriptEngine.eval(BeanShellScriptEngine.java:104)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want to check if the variable 'assignee' has a null value or not... What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `'c'` is a character literal, but `''` (a character literal for "no character"?) is *invalid Java syntax*. (Even if it did parse there would be a type error with `String == char`.)

Perhaps `""` (an empty String) literal was meant instead?

**Important Note:** even if this doesn't have a Syntax Error one *should generally not* compare Strings with `==` (or `!=`) as the results can be unexpected.. There are *plenty* of questions on SO as to why and how to properly compare String objects in Java: e.g. see `String.equals(..)` and `String.isEmpty()`.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Compare it directly to null:

```
if(assignee.toString() != null)
{
   do.something();
}
```